# How to test with jMeter against basic auth protected domain?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, basic-authentication

I am running a staging cluster of apache/nginx webservers where the domain has basic authentication restricted access. My goal is to test performance of the cluster with jmeter.

In order to pass the authentication I have added the HTTP Authentication controler of jmeter. This works, BUT every request shows two logentries at apache. One 200 and one 401. This is normal behavior as of the first request the user must be authenticated. Unfortunatelly, jmeter does this on every request.

How can I make sure that each thread/user only requests access once. Or even better, how could I grant jmeter access with without every user needing to authenticat. I believe that this will impact the test results.

Thank you for any hint on this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a JMeter bug as given proper "Authorization" header is provided there shouldn't be WWW-Authenticate challenge. If you could file it via [JMeter Bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) or flag it via [JMeter Users Mailing List](http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html#JMeterUser) that would be great

In the meantime you can work it around using one of the following approaches:

1. Inject credentials directly into URL - in case of JMeter into "Path" input field like:

   ```
   http://username:password@host.domain/path
   ```

   [image: Basic Auth 1 - credentials in URL]
2. Use Beanshell Scripting to construct proper "Authorization" header on-the-fly. In order to do so:

   - Make sure that [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) is present. If not - add it on Test Plan level or as a child of the HTTP Request which needs to be authenticated
   - add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of HTTP Request which needs to be authenticated
   - Provide username and password separated by space via "Parameters" input
   - Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area

     ```
     import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder;
     import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

     String encodedCredentials = Base64Encoder.encode(bsh.args[0] + ":" + bsh.args[1]);
     sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials));
     ```

   [image: Beanshell PreProcessor - authentication]

You shouldn't be receiving any 401 codes anywhere anymore.